# Supervisor wants my paper in another conference, but I have paid for travel for the current one

Tags: publications, journals, conference

My supervisor wants the paper at another huge conference where all the funding are given and it's more valid than the current accepted one. But I have paid all my air fares and hotel fares for the current travel. Refunding is not possible it seems. Can I go to a conference and just present without publishing?

I can't waste my money by just avoiding the conference. I have to take something out of it.

Comment: @scaaahu Yes. He is a co-author. And he is a young lecturer and not financially well. And he was not willing to come to this current conference as he have to spend his own money. He told me to attend the conference alone. Now another conference has accepted the paper and funds are also given by them so he is planning to go to that one. And Now he is telling me not to publish as he is going to publish in this new conference. And he don't want any self plagiarism issues. He too worked hard for the research. But now the problem is i have invested the money. What shall I do. ?

Comment: Sorry about the deletion of my previous comment. Your problem seems to be more complex than what you said in your question. I think not only you have the travel expenses concern, but also the double submission issue. Have you withdraw the paper from the current conference?

Comment: * The conference i have paid a no-show policy. If i present only it will added to IEEE digital library and proceedings.

* Maybe that another conference is good one and that will also submit to IEEE and this will cause a conflict.

* That supervisor' conference is after a month after my current conference. I have not withdrawn yet & if do they may actually reject my registration as well. So my airfares and hotel fares are into hell. they cant be refunded as i know. I thought of just going to the conference and meet people and come back. At-least for some knowledge & enjoyable trip.

Comment: "I thought of just going to the conference and meet people and come back. At-least for some knowledge & enjoyable trip." This sounds like your worst case scenario, and it sounds like a good idea in any case. If the paper is presented in the other conference, would you be going there with your supervisor? If yes, would you be able to present there? And would you have to pay for the trip yourself?

Comment: @T.Verron That co-author/Supervisor is a cunning fellow. He refused this first conference because he don't like paying money himself. He told me if you can pay and go then go. Now when he thinks their is free opportunity , he is trying to go there and not caring of funds i paid for this.
It seems like he will file some disputes against me in the university if i publish. I have to pay again if i am going with him. Funds are only for him through some charity

Comment: **Fire your advisor.**

Comment: Unethical multiple submission aside, your complaint about the non-refundable fee sounds like a sunk cost fallacy. "I already paid for this conference so it is wasteful not to go" is a common feeling, but is not necessarily in your best interest. You have already "lost" the money for the conference regardless of whether you go or not. You should base your decision of whether to go on what you might *gain* by going, not what you have already lost.

Comment: @ff524 If the conference is in Hawaii and having paid the tickets and hotel to go there, it would be a shame not to go. If the conference is in an unknown, mediocre place it might make sense not to go.

Comment: @Alexandros exactly. If the conference is in Hawaii, there would almost certainly be something to gain by going :) Not because otherwise the fees paid would be "wasted" - that's in the past - but because there's some actual benefit to going. (Educational, recreational, or other benefit.)

Comment: @Alexandros: Interestingly, the more unknown a place is, the more difficult it gets to find out whether it is actually mediocre after all without going there and checking for oneself ;) (And with that said, lots of well-known places are actually very mediocre, in spite of the hype created around their excellence.)

Answer (score 11):

There is only one solution:

- The paper has been accepted on first conference.
- You paid for going there
- You go there and present the paper.
- Withdraw from second conference ASAP (like Monday morning after notifying your adrvisor).
- Search for new advisor, because him a) advising double (or multiple) submission of the same paper and b) pay travel costs from your own pocket for first conference, shows he knows nothing about how academia works.

Comment: He is not telling me to double submissions ?

What he said was, i am going publish this research in a another conference. He said me not to publish in this conference i have paid. 

Is that a good idea to attend a conference and not publish. And what reasons i can tell the conference organizers to avoid bad name for the authors

Comment: When you submitted to first conference, has he agreed to that? When your paper got accepted, and you paid the costs, has he agreed to that? If the answer is yes, then that is the end of story,

Comment: Yes he agreed. But he is now planning to publish in another conference. He has also worked around 50% in the research and he claims that he has done equal work. For me its fine. If he is publishing i will also get a publication entry. but sad thing is he doesn't care about the money i spend. He is talking self centered.

Comment: Repeat after me. a) He cannot publish in another conference if he does not withdraw from first, because this is double submission. b) He does not know if the paper will be accepted from 2nd conference c) He cannot submit on 2nd conference or withdraw from first without the consent of all co-authors (you). d) He should pay you the money for first conference, because you planned for this trip with his consent and he is the one changing his mind.

Comment: One of the big mistakes we did was. We sent our paper to multiple conferences in fond of getting at least selected in one. The conference I paid to travel has a no show policy. if i don't present the paper will auto withdrawn. He asked me to refund money or go to conference stay way from presenting. refunding is impossible at the stage and it will be a huge loss for me. And another issue is filing something against him will create some issues in my academics and results. My parents told me just visit the conference learn something and come back like a edu trip. He will backfire in my academics

Comment: @arjino _We sent our paper to multiple conferences_ This is called multiple submission.

Comment: @scaaahu Yes :)

Comment: You should walk away ASAP from everyone suggesting submitting the same paper to multiple conferences or journals at the same time. He is either a) an idiot b) unethical or c) clueless and sooner or later he will drag you down with him.

Comment: @Alexandros AGREED he is an unethical guy. 100% True.

Lets consider this case. Lets say he has won the war and some of the higher officials have approved the second conference is the best place to present. In this case, what is the best solution to make my spent money useful. ?

Comment: No NO @Alexandros. The paper has been accepted for presentation in the second conference. That's the actual issue here. Her wanted to go there and he tell me not to publish in the first one. IN a normal case i am ok with that. Now i have paid my fares and what is the best solution. I dont to create big problem in the university regarding this and this will backfire on me

Comment: Then withdraw from first conference, he pays you the money you gave for first conference, he goes and present the paper in second conference and then you find a new advisor. If he does not give the money for first conference then you go there and have a vacation but you still have to find a new advisor.

Comment: What my well wishers told was. Go there, meet new researchers, share knowledge, listen to ideas, Do some sight seeing, Have fun, make use of the money (Social events & Banquets). And my problem is what is the best reason i can tell the first conference organizers to withdraw my paper and doesn't affect my reputation. Some valid reason. can you suggest. i dont want to talk all these issues there. it ill be headache

Comment: _what is the best reason i can tell the first conference organizers to withdraw my paper_ — You don't need a reason; just withdraw the paper.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are focusing on the wrong issue. The multiple-submission issue may have long term consequences. It would be a problem even if you could get a complete refund of your costs for attending the first conference.

Before making any decisions, I suggest carefully reviewing all paperwork you or your advisor have submitted for each conference. You may, for example, have already assigned the copyright to the paper to one of the conferences. If so, you are better off withdrawing from the other conference. If you have assigned it to both, the situation is much more difficult.

Do not make up a reason for withdrawal. Conferences that might both accept the same paper are a small world. It is likely that the organizers of the first conference will at least scan the proceedings of the second one, and see your paper there.